# Improving performance on bitmap images decoding on translating into view

Tags: css, performance, transform, render, paintevent

I'm developing an application which involves a slides translating into view as the primary navigation mechanism. The first slide to come in involves several super-imposed PNGs at roughly 2000px squared with transparencies, and there's a notable framerate stutter as the images come into view.

Using Chrome Dev Tools' Timeline feature I've established that while most of the individual Paint tasks take under 5 milliseconds each, the significant outliers are those Paint events whose subtasks include decoding the PNGs, which take between 50 and 100 milliseconds one after the other, seemingly at the moment the images come into view.

Ideally I would like to decode the bitmaps ahead of time, but I can't think of a way of forcing this behaviour without actually rendering them in view. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you may need to take advantage of hardware acceleration. Take a look at: http://threejs.org/

Comment: Use `transform` with `translate3d` to resolve this. Use in place of `left` and `top`.

Comment: @Ruirize the transitions are being applied to 3D translations. It effectively defers to GPU and is certainly much smoother than left / right animations. The problem lies in decoding the PNG images ahead of time.

Comment: @Diodeus GPU processing is already in use. three.js does offer granular control over image decoding, but invoking a 3D library for the benefit of enhancing the performance of a couple of bitmaps in a DOM structure would involve far too much hacks work to pull off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bottleneck is decoding, then pre-render your images to a canvas, and then either draw those pre-rendered canvases to your view canvas or translate them in using CSS.